# How To Set Root Password in MySQL 5.7 from a Shell Script Over SSH

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation

We need to be able to install MySQL 5.7 using a shell script (over SSH) and then set the password in the same script without manual intervention. Our current shell script installs MySQL 5.7 on a Ubuntu server using the following commands:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive    
sudo -E apt-get -q -y install mysql-server-5.7
```

This allows MySQL to be installed without prompts. However, it also creates the 'root' user without a password. So, in the script we attempt to set the password using:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password abc123
```

This produces the following error message and does not set the password:

```
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
```

The script is being run over a (secure) SSH connection but the password is not set. We also tried calling multiple variations of the following command using the MySQL CLI without success:

```
sudo mysql -u root -e "use mysql;update user set authentication_string=password('abc123') where user='root';flush privileges;
```

**SOLVED**

I found an explanation of the problem and a solution here:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Here's the solution:

```
sudo mysql -u root -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'newPassword';"
```

This can be used in a script for automated installs.

Comment: try this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127537/setting-root-password-in-fresh-mysql-5-7-installation

Comment: We've tried all of method described in that post. We can manually set it mysql_secure_installation, but the script needs to run unattended. This appears to be a wide-spread issue with MySQL 5.7.

Comment: really ? very strange... because i had the same issue few months ago after installing MySql 5.7 , and i remember that this is what i did ... i entered to mysql_safe mode and reset my password.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. We can 'manually' reset the password using mysql_secure_installation. Want we cannot do is set/reset the password in a script.

Comment: i saw you found the way :) thanks for updating.so all you needed was to run with sudo